# Why am I getting a NoMethodError in Users#index error (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I looked at lot of the other threads and spent the past few hours looking over it but I still haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm using a same line of code from another view page

Here's the error:

`app/views/users/_user.html.erb` where line #4 raised:

```
undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass
```

This is from the Rubytutorial demo app if you're familiar with that. This code was used in `views\users\show.html.erb` and I tried to see if it will work on `views\users\ _user.html.erb` but I get the error.

The code that I'm reusing is:

```
<%= @user.microposts.count %>
```

Here's the complete view (_user.html.erb) that calls the partial

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
<%- if @user %>
  <%= @user.microposts.count %>
<%- else %>
  THIS IS THE ERROR, THERE IS NO USER ON @user
<%- end %>
 <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Which results in THIS IS THE ERROR, THERE IS NO USER ON \@user. which means that on the partial, \@user doesn't exists as per rorra's comments so where do I fix this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def index

    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end



  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Sample App!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end


  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Here's the views\users\index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Users') %>
<h1>Users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>

</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

And here's the views\users\show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>

    </section>
  <br>
  </aside>


  <div class="span10">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.empty? %>
<h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
<% end %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>

      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is, User model is associated with Micropost model?

Comment: I'm pretty new to RoR. Can you explain further on how to do that? Here's the beginning of the User model which has microposts. class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

Comment: Where are you calling this partial and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your partial (\views\users\_user.html.erb) with this code:

```
<%- if @user %>
  <%= @user.microposts.count %>
<%- else %>
  THIS IS THE ERROR, THERE IS NO USER ON @user
<%- end %>
```

and you will get the last phrase :P

The problem is that @user on the partial is a nil object, instead of having a User object

If you are calling the partial from your **show** action, then you shouldn't have a nil object since if @user is nil, it will throw an exception on the second line of your action (and it won't reach the partial).

Now, something that is confusing for new developers, is that on the partials, you usually pass a object, whose name is the name of the partial, so if your partial, as in this case, is named **_user**, and you pass a default object to this partial, then you will be able to reference the object by using the variable **user** instead of the instance variable **@user**

try this code as well on your view:

```
<%= user.microposts.count %>
```

in order to make that work, you will usually send the object like

```
<%= render partial: '/views/users/user', object: @my_user %>
```

or even

```
<%= render @user %>
```

which will look for the view _user.html.erb

You usually use those partials to render collections, like

```
<%= render partial: '/views/users/user', collection: @users %>
```

For more information, just read the [Rails Guide about partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

---

The partial should look like this:

```
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      <%= user.microposts.count %>
      <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
```

The way you call the partial from index.html.erb with

```
<%= render @users %>
```

its totally fine

what gem are you using for pagination? I think that the problem is that **paginate** returns an ActiveRecord relation, and not an array with each user.

Update your controller **index** action to:

```
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).all
```

Comment: Hmmm, the first method doesn't pull in the # of microposts and the second method gives me this error:  ArgumentError in Users#index

Showing C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/views/users/_user.html.erb where line #4 raised:

'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <li>
2:   <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
3:   <%= link_to user.name, user %>
4: <%= render @user %> 
5: <%= user.microposts.count %>

Comment: I got lost. I didn't put a first, second or third method, just explained about partials and variables on it. The first block of code, however, should show on screen: THIS IS THE ERROR, THERE IS NO USER ON \@user.
Which means that on the partial, \@user doesn't exists.

Comment: You have written the content of the partial, and the controller, try to update your question with the view that calls the partial and then we will be able to discover the error. Nevertheless, if you go though the Rails Guide about partial, and you read it, you should be able to discover the error right away.

Comment: Rorra, I updated the question with the view that calls the partial. How does it look now? Right now, it shows THIS IS THE ERROR, THERE IS NO USER ON \@user on the screen.

Comment: Because on the partial, @user doesn't reference to any variable. Put the complete logic, the code for the controller and the view who is calling the partial, and I'll be able to let you know what's the issue.

Comment: I posted up the complete codes for the controller and view on who is calling the partial at the bottom of my post. Do you see the issue?

Comment: which is the request that is failing? http://localhost:3000/users ? or http://localhost:3000/users/1 ? and you are still misisng the views (where the error happens, like /users/index.html.erb, or /users/show.html.erb, you are only putting the partial

Comment: Request that is failing is localhost:3000/users. I posted up the rest of the views for your reference

Comment: check my new comments, it should work with these fixes, but most important you should understand why its failing :)

Comment: You are the man. Thanks for the help. I am going to try to understand what happened here and hope this helps someone else out there

Comment: NP, remember a positive vote on my answer and select is as "accepted", improving my reputation helps me to get better contracts :)